# Hot to Add Include DropDown List in ASP.net in my code below. I want to Include foreign table Item Location to my Item table

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, foreign-keys, dropdown

Below is my HTTP GET and HTTP POST Codes. I want to add .Include Item Location for my drop down list. Please help identity where I can add the Include for my Item Location on below code. Thank you!

Below Is my HTTPGET Method...

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddOrEditItem(int id = 0)
        {


            Item item = new Item();
            if (id != 0)
            {
                using (erpdb db = new erpdb ())
                {
                    item = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemId == id).FirstOrDefault<Item>();
                }
            }



            return View(item);
        }
```

Below Is my HTTPPOST Method

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddOrEditItem(Item item)
        {
            try
            {

                using (erpdb = new erpdb())
                {
                    if (item.ItemId == 0)
                    {
                        db.Items.Add(item);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                return Json(new { success = true, html = GlobalClass.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "ViewAllItems", GetAllItems()), message = "Submitted Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Please help how can I add my Item Location so that it can be selected on my dropdownlist view and as well as saved

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own issue myself by doing the following:
Step 1: Creating a viewmodel for items so that I can include item location on my form
Step 2: added .Include when calling the database so that I can include it to my indes view of items